# Viewcontroller loaded twice

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying create Tab Bar application. I added to the first viewcontroller a button and a text field. When I wrote some text and pushed button I expected that loads second viewcontroller and in the label field appears text from the text field.

I have 2 problems.

1. Second viewcontroller loaded twice.
2. when I push button on tab bar and load first viewcontroller again? me text disappear.

I only start work with Xcode. Help me please and describe resolve in details

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit

var tfTextString: String = ""

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func enter(_ sender: Any) {
        if textField.text != "" {
            //performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
            //tfTextString = textField.text!
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var secondController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        secondController.myString = textField.text!
    }
}

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    var myString = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = myString
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant code but based on your storyboard image, I would expect the second view controller to be loaded twice - once by the tab bar controller and then again when you push it from the first view controller.

Comment: Do not paste screen shots of code. Please include actual code, in text, formatted using the code block formatting tool {}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't post images. Post code (text).

Comment: I edit the question. Can you ask me how can I do it right?

Comment: As I said, you have two instances of second view controller, one you have push from the first view controller and one that is in the tab bar controller.  These are separate instances with separate properties, so the one in the tab bar has no text value since it’s property was never set.

Comment: How can I create only one viewcontroller?

Comment: can you tell me the Swift version?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your view controller is loaded twice because you are *loading* it twice.

Don't think of each screen on the storyboard as being it's own distinct entity as per the singleton pattern.  They aren't.  They're their own distinct class / view combination, which gets *instantiated* (loaded) once every time you call it.  To put it another way, you aren't looking at the 'actual' classes in the storyboard, you're looking at the template that's used to build the class when called for.  So you're calling for it twice, in two different places, and it happily produces multiple copies of the underlying view / controller for you.

I think you don't want to use a navigation controller to 'push' the view back onto the stack.  You're going to want to tell the tab bar to switch to a different view instead.

The swift version of the code you're looking for is:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

I think the objective-C equivalent would have been...

```
[[self tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:1];
```

But it's been long enough since I've done swift I may have overlooked something important in there.

Comment: But if I don't use navigation controller I can't see tab bar when I push button and load second viewcontroller

Comment: @ElenaKireeva that was your first clue that you were using the wrong code.  You don't want to instantiate a new copy of the VC, you want to switch to the existing copy on the tab bar view controller.

Comment: Yes, but when I try to show tab bar at the second view controller I can do it with use navigation controller. How can I save tab bar without navigation controller?

Comment: @ElenaKireeva I'm sorry, could you rephrase your question?  I understand English is your second language, but you're going to need to make more effort to be clear -- your question is just this side of gibberish and I just can't make heads or tails of it.